# How can I get a button to span the width of the card that it is contained in?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using Angular v6 and Angular Material to build a front page for a web project. I was wondering, how can I have the width of the button stretch to match the width of the material card component that it appears in?

Here's my code:

```html
<div style="padding:5px">
  <mat-card>
    <button mat-button style="background-color: #008CBA; width:100%;">Portfolio</button>
    <button mat-button style="background-color: #008CBA; width:100%;">Portfolio</button>
    <button mat-button style="background-color: #008CBA; width:100%;">Portfolio</button>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: OP, please consider using the [tag:angular-material] tag instead of the [tag:material] tag as the `material` tag is ambiguous. Also, please consider posting your code in the question itself, instead of as an image so that it is easier to view for others. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For something like this, normally adding:

```
style="width: 100%; display: block;"
```

in the button would stretch it. If that doesn't work, go into inspect element of the button and make sure that max-width isn't set to anything lower than 100% (try display: flex as well).

Please give an example of your code for a more specific answer.

Comment: It's worth noting that while this does work, the Angular Material documentation warns about forwards-compatibility:

"Avoid defining custom styles that would affect the size or internal layout of the component, such as padding, height, width, or overflow. You can specify display: none to hide a component, but avoid specifying any other display value. Overriding these properties can break components in unexpected ways as the internal styles change between releases."

https://v17.material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles